# Edit component impossible

Tags: content-management-system, magnolia

I have Magnolia 5.5 and I changed the config so that I can not edit a certain type of component anymore. I forgot which changes lead to that point.

Now I have an area, in that area all the Text-image Components are not editable any more

[image]

but other components in that same area are still editable.

I have searched my config for an

```
editable : false
```

node and could not locate anything in that direction.

Can somebody point me to the parts of the config where I could have achieved such an effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in the config by looking at the hasEditButton() method in the MgnlComponent.class. I had earlier deleted the dialog property from the component. So no edit button was shown any more and editing was disabled.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are searching for this: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/Area+definition

There you can set 'editable' configuration within an Area.

Cheers,

Hope that helps,

Ilgun

Comment: thx for your answer. well I double-checked and it was not configured there. Is there an other config which would achieve such an effect? Also there are other components in that area which i can still edit so it can not be in the area-config.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the editable flag doesn't allow you to change the instance of the component via page editor.
What you see is that you have disabled edit action in the pages app which is typically done by defining availability rules for given action. [Check for more info in the documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/Action+definition#Actiondefinition-Actionavailability).

HTH,
Jan